# Prevent Samsung Galaxy S2 camera to change resolution without prompting

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, camera

I got a Samsung Galaxy SII (S2) with Android 4.1.2 and the built in camera app keeps changing the resolution from 8MP to the lowest, 640 x 480.

Why does this happen and is there any way to prevent this?